# Using Alphabetic Characters in SimpleDateFormat Pattern String

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, simpledateformat

Is it possible to include an alphabetic character in a SimpleDateFormat Pattern String?

I am trying to create a format string where the letter 'T' is included before the time for example:

2003-11-15**T**09:30:47-05:00.

I am currently using `yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ssZ` as the pattern string.

If I change it to `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ` it will throw an exception as 'A' to 'Z' and 'a' to 'z' are reserved.

Is there any solution that does not involve using two DateFormats?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Surrounding the `T` with single quotes should work:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ
```

Quoting from [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (emphasis mine):

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings. Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from `'A'` to `'Z'` and from `'a'` to `'z'` are interpreted as pattern letters representing the components of a date or time string. **Text can be quoted using single quotes (`'`) to avoid interpretation.** `"''"` represents a single quote. All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during formatting or matched against the input string during parsing.

Your specific use case is even included as an example:

```
Date and Time Pattern            Result
-------------------------------------------------------------
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"     2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
```

Comment: As documented in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, was about to add that :)