# What template should I use in SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have date formatted in this way:

```
        2010-02-04T00:00:00
```

I use this code to parse it:

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss");
        Date parsed = dateFormat.parse("2010-02-04T00:00:00");
```

It returns exception. The problem is in "T" letter. How can I parse this date if server returns it in such a format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

one can read a bit more about it here [Using Alphabetic Characters in SimpleDateFormat Pattern String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416809/using-alphabetic-characters-in-simpledateformat-pattern-string)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this string instead: `"2010-02-04'T'00:00:00".` The '-character escapes letters so they are not parsed as part of the date.

Or as the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) explains it:

> Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation.
>   "''" represents a single quote. All other characters are not
>   interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during
>   formatting or matched against the input string during parsing.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

edit lowecase `m` stays per minute in  hour. see the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd'T' hh:mm:ss z yyyy");

Date myDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
sdf2.format(myDate);

System.out.println(myDate);
```

This will work...